# various methods for estimating variance

Tags: variance, bootstrap

I have a sample drawn from a population, and I'm interested in estimating the population's variance. I'm considering several approaches, but it's difficult for me to see the tradeoffs between them.

For example let's assume my sample consists of the numbers [0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 10]. Here are the approaches I'm considering:

**1. Compute the sample variance directly**
This gives 16.89 (biased) or 20.27 (unbiased).

**2. Fit to a known distribution**
If I were willing to make assumptions about the population's distribution, then I could estimate parameters of this distribution. For example if the population were normal then I could fit my samples to a normal distribution, and take the variance of the normal distribution.

**3. Bootstrapping**
It seems that bootstrapping may be able to help me find a confidence interval for the population variance. When I attempted this, it was difficult to understand the relationship between the bootstrapping result and the variance I computed directly in **1** above.

I know this is a rather general question, but I'd like to understand whether more can be stated about the population variance beyond what I computed in **1** above. If assumptions are made (i.e. approach **2**) it makes sense that more can be known. If assumptions are not made (i.e. approach **3**), I'm curious whether anything can be learned.